# How would I go about easily fixing this error?

Tags: visual-c++

Every time I try to compile `a .sln` I always get this `error` in this specific `CPP` file.

```
Error0020
Error3861
```

Any Help?

```
// If we are in the right place where the player view is calculated
// Calculate the change in the view and get rid of it
if (Menu::Window.VisualsTab.OtherNoVisualRecoil.GetState() && (DWORD)(_ReturnAddress()) == Offsets::Functions::dwCalcPlayerView)
{
    IClientEntity* pLocalEntity = NULL;

    float* m_LocalViewAngles = NULL;

    __asm
    {
```

Comment: The compiler just says "Error0020 Error3861"? No actual error message in human language?

Answer (score 0):

Error [C3861](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3861) references a function that cannot be located by the compiler. Since you are trying to compile an existing project, does it have any documentation included on how to set up the Visual Studio linking settings?

It seems that libraries or header files that are supposed to be included are missing. The information included with the error by the compiler on its standard output should give you more information, such as *which* function is actually causing the problem.